# Can I use a template variable in another template in Golang?

Tags: templates, go

Template 1

```
{{define "one"}}
  {{ $var := "Hello"}}
{{end}}
```

Template 2

```
{{define "two"}}
  {{template "one"}}
  Say, {{print $var}}
{{end}}
```

I know the above example isn't valid. But is there a way to use the variable of `"one"` template into `"two"` template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading all the documentation. The answer seems to be *no*. When a template is executed before being embedded into another, that variable is gone and if its value is used in the template, it appears as static text.

In the example of template *one*, `$var` isn't used anywhere, so it is thrown away.

The order of execution would be.

1. Load both templates.
2. Template *one* is executed, throwing `$var` away because it wasn't used.
3. Template *two* is executed, embedding the result of template *one* in it.

If this explanation is incorrect. Please comment or edit it.

But the answer to my question is that the standard templating library doesn't pass template variables between templates. They are meant for local use.